# Github pull request builder plugin not setting jenkins build status of pull request on github

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When I raise a PR on github, then the jenkins build that is triggered should set the status of the PR on github as "Pending" and once the build is complete it should set the build status of the job on github. But in my case, jenkins doesn't set the build status of PR on github.
I am using /ghprbhook/ in github webhooks.

I have already followed this article given [here](https://medium.com/@mreigen/integrate-jenkins-builds-into-github-pull-requests-33bc053d6210) but it did not solve my problem, instead, it gave other problems.

I have also followed this [article](https://dev.to/krusenas/automated-jenkins-builds-on-github-pull-request-4lh2) but it also did not help and instead raise a few other problems.

I tried triggering jenkins build using github pull request builder plugin on my localhost and in that case it works perfectly well and posted the PR build status on github. But when I try the same thing on the server where jenkins is hosted with exactly the same pipeline configuration as in localhost I face the above issue of build status not posting on github.

I am attaching the screenshot of console output when I run on localhost below
[image: localhost image]

This is the image of the console output of the jenkins job build that is hosted on the server.

[image: jenkins hosted on server console image]
as you can see in both the images above, the localhost image's second line is responsible for setting the build status to pending when the build starts but in the server image that **"Setting status to...."** line is missing and instead an error line like **"Unable to query github for status..."** is there. I think that error line is preventing jenkins from posting the status back to github.

I am attaching the pipeline config also
[image: pipeline config]

Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can retry it now. GitHub had incident on 2019-08-22 10:59 UTC for some hours. See it: https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/nt6n1hs8bk3v

Comment: this can't be the issue in my case as the problem persists from quite some time.